# Weighted Average in Excel, 2 different results

Tags: excel, weighted-average, sumproduct

[image: Weighted Average]

Hi all,

I have something that I cannot explain.

Here is an explanation of the table
Weight
Price Increase in %
Old Price
New Price = ( Old Price * Price Increase ) + Old Price
Total Old Price = Old Price * Weight
Total New Price = New Price * Weight

When using SumProduct to calculate the weighted average I get
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A6,B2:B6)/SUM(A2:A6) = 16.1072%

But a Finance guy told me that was wrong that I needed to calculate it like this
=SUM(F2:F6)/SUM(E2:E6)-1 = 16.2465%

1 - Why is it giving different results
2 - Who is right

Anyone able to shed some light on this would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: What parameter are you trying to calculate a weighted average of?

Comment: It is the average weighted Price increase.

Comment: Your finance guy is calculating the average increase in price for each lot.

Comment: Thanks Ron but I am not sure what you mean by that exactly.  Can you elaborate a little bit more ?

Comment: He is calculating the percent increase of your total holdings. That is just not the same as the "average weighted price increase".  Your old holdings were worth `131,610.00`. Your new holdings are worth `152,992.00`. So the value of your holdings increased by `16.2465%`